# How do I replace text inside a paragraph inside a div element?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I need to set the text within a Paragraph that is within a DIV element dynamically. I know the divID and can get the div by id using get document.getElementById(divID)
This returns the following:

```
<div id="mynote72031" class="mydiv" ondrop="drop(event,this.id)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="cursor: move; display: block; top: 19px; left: 19px; width: 375px;">
  <a style="top:0px; right:5px;  position:absolute; color:#F00" href="javascript:;" onclick="hideElement(this)">X</a>
  <p id="noteContent1" ondblclick="editContent(this)">Note Number: 1</p>
</div>
```

The function should look like this:

```
function updateNote(divID, paragraphInnerHTML) {
  var updateNoteP = document.getElementById(divID);
  //Update Paragraph inside the DIV here
}
```

Note that the id of the paragraph is always noteContent1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 ways you can change the text within HTML tag

```js
function updateNote(divID, paragraphInnerHTML) {
  var updateNoteP = document.getElementById(divID);
  //Update Paragraph inside the DIV here
  let $targetEle = updateNoteP.childNodes[1]
  // use innerHTML
  $targetEle.innerHTML = paragraphInnerHTML
  // or textContext
  $targetEle.textContent = paragraphInnerHTML 
}
```

Comment: That replaces the div innerHTML with the paragraph innerHTML. getElementById(divID) returns the div, not the inner paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Node.lastChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/lastChild) to access the `p` tag as it is the last element within the `div` tag

```
function updateNote(divID, paragraphInnerHTML) {
    var updateNoteP = document.getElementById(divID);
    //Update Paragraph inside the DIV here
    let pElement = updateNoteP.lastChild;
    pElement.innerHTML = paragraphInnerHTML;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty close with your variable name, this assumes that it's html you wanna use. If it's just a string you can use updateNoteP.innerText instead

If you pass in pID as "noteContent1" this will change the content of the P

```
function updateNote(pID, paragraphInnerHTML) {
  var updateNoteP = document.getElementById(divID);
  // check that element is found
  if (updateNoteP) {
  // update inner html
   updateNoteP.parentElement.children[1].innerHTML = paragraphInnerHTML
  }
}
```

Comment: That replaces the div innerHTML with the paragraph innerHTML. getElementById returns the div, not the inner paragraph. After performing this function both the <a> and the <p> elements inside the div are replaced by paragraphInnerHTML.

Comment: updated answer.

Comment: Unfortunately noteContent1 is not unique in this case. The Div ID is unique, but not the inner paragraph id.

Comment: Ahh I see, updated.